# How to balance classes with random forest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have a problem with unbalanced classes. The classes are 0,1,2

The class 0 is very unbalanced with respect to classes 1, 2

here is my code:

```
parameters = [{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100]},
              {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-2,1e-3, 1e-4],'C': [1, 10, 1000, 5000], }]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer( ngram_range=(1, 20))
clf=GridSearchCV(SVC(class_weight='balanced'),parameters,cv=2,refit=True)
model= make_pipeline(tfidf,clf)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)



print("Best parameters set:",clf.best_params_)
print("Grid scores on every set of parameters:")
print()
means = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, clf.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.04f) for %r"
              % (mean, std * 2, params))


print()
print("Classification report:")
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print("Test accuracy:",accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
labels = model.classes_
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
print(pd.DataFrame(matrix,columns=labels, index=labels))
plot_confusion_matrix(matrix,labels)
```

The Results:
[image]

From the confusion matrix I see that the classes are not well balanced. How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: It is quite possible that majority of your X_test data belongs to **CLASS 0** and that is what is being reflected in your predictions.
In order to test whether the class imbalance has been taken into consideration by the model, run the prediction on X_train (taking equal rows of all classes ) and check the Confusion Matrix

Comment: how can i balance the classes?

Comment: your classes are balanced, since you are using class_weight='balanced'. The results that you are seeing is because of the test data itself. If you want to further play with the weights, you have to pass the class weights explicitly

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean they are not well-balanced? Did you consider that your original dataframe also could be disbalanced?
You should also like at the distribution of your `y` (`y_train`) and (`y_test`) , i would asusme that the most data is in class 0.
You should also run a dummy-classifier from scikit learn (strategy:most frequent) to see what accuracy and confusionmatrix this strategy would lead to, I would assume this test accuracy would be around 0,8 then.